# Smashoperator with unicode-math and luatex

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, mathtools

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,openright,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
 L(x)= \smashoperator{\sum_{x-x_j}^m}
\]
\end{document}
```

which when compiled with `lualatex` from TexLive 2021 results in thin black lines appearing above the sub- and super-scripts.

[image]

Commenting out unicode-math resolves the issue as does using `xelatex`.

Comment: I do not see the lines with a texlive 2021 updated today. I do get warnings from `lualatex-math` about an unexpected definition of cramped.

Comment: I have been able to reproduce on a Linux machine and macOS with LuaTeX, Version 1.13.0 (TeX Live 2021).  However, the issue could well have been resolved upstream.